# polkadot-js balances.transfer throws error

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

In  my webapp `balances.transfer` is throwing an error but `staking.bondExtra` is working as expected. Its connected to westend network.

Error:

> Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding balances.transfer:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"LookupSource","value":"Compact<Balance>"}:: Struct: failed on value: Compact<Balance>:: Assertion failed

Code snippet:

```
transactions = []
transactions.push(
    api.tx.staking.bondExtra(rawAmount),
    api.tx.balances.transfer(Address, commission);
);

const bondExtraFee = await api.tx.utility.batch(transactions).paymentInfo(substrateStashId);
return bondExtraFee.partialFee.toNumber();
```

Comment: are you using the latest api version? What one exactly?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by the large number of decimals in your chain.
Make sure to specify balance value as `BigInt` or `BN` instead of just `number`.